# Can you use pipenv in your Azure Pipeline steps to install dependencies?

Tags: azure-pipelines, pipenv

The Azure Pipeline example shows using pip to install requirements.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/python?view=azure-devops

```
- script: pip install -r requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install requirements'
```

The long awaited `pip -p` is not available, so what is a Pythonista to do when you've been using `pipenv` and you have `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` but no `requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can. First generate a requirements.txt and then install from it.

```
- script: python -m pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Create requirements.txt from Pipfile'
- script: pip install -r requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install requirements.txt'
```

After I posted my question, I found the `pipenv lock -r` in the docs.
https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/advanced/#generating-a-requirements-txt

Comment: I would just like to add that the syntax seems to have changed, now it's `python -m pipenv requirements > requirements.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `pipenv` directly.

```yaml
- script: pip install pipenv
  displayName: 'Making sure pipenv is installed'

- script: python -m pipenv install
  displayName: 'Installing dependencies'
```

If your `Pipfile` is not located in the top level of your repo, you will need to specify the `workingDirectory` to where it is located.

```yaml
- script: python -m pipenv install
  workingDirectory: path/to/Pipfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipenv -r option works only with version "2022.7.24". -r option deprecated in the latest pipenv versions.

Use pipenv==2022.7.24 to fix the -r command option.

```
    python -m pip install pipenv==2022.7.24
    python -m pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt
    pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to that?
Requirements is still in the "latest" documentation: 
https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/basics/#importing-from-requirements-txt

Comment: https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/changelog/#id61 - 
The deprecated way of generating requirements install -r or lock -r has been removed in favor of the pipenv requirements command. #5200
https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/pull/5200